# QT- Installation in Windows 7

Tags: windows, qt, configuration, installation

I have a c++ project that requires me to install QT when i build that project a dialog box that wants me to type in the qmake command.

I found somewhere that one needs to use

```
MinGW_QT
```

In the tools options but since i have downloaded QT libraries 4.8.4 i am  not able to find the 
.
    C:\QT\4.8.4\MinGW\bin

Which library i must install to get this also i had tried to install

```
 Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Windows (minGW 4.4, 317 MB) from the QT webportal
```

when i try to run it prompted that

```
There is a problem with your MinQW instalation
w32api not found in c:\MinGW\bin\
Do you still want to continue? Yes
```

Comment: Qt can build without MinGW with Visual Studio. Which compiler are your using?

Comment: MinGW with NetBeans 7.1.1

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Qt libraries compiled with MinGW, you will need a MinGW installation to compile and link against Qt libs. Just download and extract MinGW somewhere and add its path to your environment variable `PATH`. Then you will need to introduce that compiler to your Qt Creator installation. Go to "Tools -> Options -> Build & Run" and in toolchainn tab add your new MinGW installation.

I will suggest MinGW-builds from 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds